# React Setting State from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a function which I'm going to use in a lot of screens and I don't want to copy-paste it in every screen component so I created a new component
inputValidation.js and put the function there

```
export function validate(text,type) {
    emailPattern=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    if (type=='username'){
        if (emailPattern.test(text)){
            setState({ validUsername: true })
        } else {
            setState({ validUsername: false })
        }
    }
    if (type=='password'){
        if (text.length < 8){
            this.setState({ validPassword: false })
        } else {
            this.setState({ validPassword: true })
        }
    }
}
```

and I imported it in my screen component like this 
loginScreen.js

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = { header: null };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            validUsername: false,
            password: '',
            validPassword: false,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={styles.container}> 
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>

                    <Item style={styles.inputContainer} success={this.state.validUsername ? true : false} bordered regular>

                        <Input
                        onChangeText={(text) => validate(text,'username')}
                        autoCapitalize="none" 
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        style={styles.input} 
                        placeholder='Email' />

                        <Icon style={styles.inputIcon, !this.state.validUsername ? styles.inputIconHidden : null} type='Entypo' name='check' />

                    </Item>
                </View>

          </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

but I get error can't find variable: `setState`

I am new to react native so what's wrong ? it was working just fine before I copy-paste the function on another file

Comment: in the function file, the reference to this is different from your component's so one thing you can do is, pass this reference to your function file, or you can call the function and set the state in the component ( which is the ideal solution ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be able to do something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        validUsername: false,
        password: '',
        validPassword: false,
    };
    this.validate = validate.bind(this);
}

...


              <Input
                onChangeText={(text) => this.validate(text,'username')}
```

This should make it so that inside the `validate` function, `this` is bound to your React component and `this.setState()` thus has a meaning and context.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but is it a good practice to do something like this?

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice. Everything involved is explicit and everything has its place. I actually think it's fairly clean, compared to copy-pasting the 'validate' function everywhere it's required. I'm just annoyed with myself that I only thought of this to answer someone elses' question, and haven't used it myself! I could have been using this for ages.

Comment: This wedges a hidden dependency in the validation code--while it would *work*, it is a hidden coupling without any need to do so. If you're going to go this route then I'd just pass either `setState` itself, or an object that implements `setState` like `this` instead of a hidden binding requirement. You use the word "explicit" differently than I do.

Comment: I agree its clean, or rather its concise. I guess my concern was getting at the same issue as Dave's comment. It seems more explicit to pass it a function like `setErrors` that calls `setState`, so that its fully understood what the function's requirements are. The drawback being you need to declare a new function in each component using it.

Comment: @DaveNewton fair enough, I wouldn't disagree with that suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Just `setState` alone makes no sense (and it never should have worked) because it's an instance function. Since it's an instance function it *also* won't work because `this` will be (roughly) meaningless out of a class instance context.

You *could* pass  the `setState` function along, but that's a road to despair.

Since this is tied to `username` and `password` fields you should just have a separate component you bring in to the pages.

If that doesn't work then separate the concerns of "validation" and "what to do with validation results" and don't tie validation to a specific implementation of the validation process.